# Earned Club Nintendo gold status at end of year and now it's gone?

Tags: club-nintendo

In late June was when I earned gold status for Club Nintendo, and now it's the beginning of new Club Nintendo year and my status is gone (right in time for the rewards).  Is it worth asking Nintendo to make some sort of exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their year runs July 1 to June 30,so since it is past that date, your status rolled over to the new year and any progress you had towards Gold or Platinum has been reset. If you qualified before the end of the year, you will still get whatever rewards related to that, but otherwise you are just going to have to try again this year. Nintendo is unlikely to make an exception, because this is not an error on their part, and it would then open them up to a lot of people effectively wanting to circumvent the rules and such that they have placed around when the status rolls over.

Comment: The elite status gifts for 2013 are gone though, right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. They just announced the gifts for the year that ended this June, so if you don't see that, then it is likely you didn't qualify. You can check your coin status though, somewhere, and see (it will mention years you qualified for elite status, all the games you registered, how many coins you have, etc)

Comment: Sorry, what I'm saying is that I got elite status June of this year, which is technically last year for Nintendo.  But the rewards from last year are all gone, right?

Comment: No - they are all downloadable items, you should see them [here](https://club.nintendo.com/elite-status-gifts.do) when you are signed in (or there will be a banner you can click. IF you don't see that, then likely you didn't qualify.

Comment: Oh wait.  It turns out I did qualify after all!

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear!

Comment: I'm 90% sure that I got gold and it's telling me that I don't qualify either.

Comment: @Brian I don't know what to do in that case - I've never had them be wrong. Perhaps add up your coins, and see, and if it doesn't work out in a way that makes sense, message Nintendo?

Answer (score 2):

Gold and Platinum statuses roll over July 1st of every year. This is outlined in their [Club Nintendo Year End FAQ](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8564/p/52/session/L3RpbWUvMTQwNTUyNjU1OC9zaWQvc3J4OHpyWmw%3D):

> - Every Club Nintendo member that has reached Gold Status (300 Coins) or Platinum Status (600 Coins) for the current Club Nintendo year will earn an Elite Status Gift. Gold and Platinum members can place an order as soon as the Elite Status gifts are revealed (usually around the middle of July).
> - Any unused Coins earned more than two years ago will expire. (For example, all unused Coins earned in June 2012 or earlier expire on July 1, 2014.)
> - **The Elite Status progress bar (in the upper-right corner of the Club Nintendo homepage) will return to 0 and the status will reset for the new Club Nintendo year.**

I bolded the last bullet point, which is relevant to your question. Seeing as this system is working as intended, you wouldn't be able to receive an exception. The intention is that you rebuild up your points every year to receive the new rewards.